# Turning utf in their real symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just made the first web scraper by myself which goes onto wikipedia and downloads the html of the whole page. I managed to get just the content of a list. the values on the list contain numbers either positive or negative.
But instead of printing out a `'-2'` it gives me a `'\xe2\x88\x922'` . I tried the `string.replace("\xe2\x88\x92","-")` but this doesn't seem to work due to the backslashes.
do you know how I can convert these utf things into their real symbol ?
I used urllib to get the html content if this is important.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert it:

```
>>> b'\xe2\x88\x922'.decode("utf8")
'-2'
```

And if your data doesn't start with `b` (i.e. if it is not a `bytes` object), you can first convert it to `bytes` then decode:

```
>>> s = '\xe2\x88\x922'
>>> byte_object = bytes(ord(c) for c in s)
>>> byte_object.decode("utf8")
'-2'
```

Answer (score 3):

That is unfortunately common when reading data from web pages: they contain characters looking like standard ASCII characters but that are not.

Here you have a MINUS character (unicode U+2212) `−` which looks like the normal HYPHEN-MINUS (unicode U+002D or ASCII 0x2D) `-`.

In UTF8 it is encoded as `b'\xe2\x88\x922'`. It probably means that you read it as if it was Latin1 encoded while it is UTF8 encoded.

A trick the correctly recode it is to encode it as Latin1 and decode it back:

```
t =  '\xe2\x88\x922' 
print(t.encode('latin1').decode()

−2
```